# External monitor only shows desktop's background

Tags: windows, tv, external-display

I have an USB to HDMI adapter/converter (DisplayLink) and a HDMI to HDMI cable. I've connected one end to the adapter and the other end to my 19" flat screen Samsung TV's HDMI port, to use my TV as a monitor. I installed, successfully, the new adapter's hardware, using the driver CD.

However, I'm not able to watch any of my PC's videos on the TV. It only shows the background picture of my desktop. It is not responding at all.

Any help?

Answer (score 5):

Your display is set to **Extend**, which means you have two desktops now: the internal display  and the TV.

This isn't necessarily a bad thing. You can drag windows from your internal display to the TV (and back). Just use your mouse as if it was one big display. The extended desktop is to the right of the regular one:

[image: illustration]

If you want to disable this feature:

- In Windows 7, you can press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> repeatedly to cycle through the different display options:

  - Computer only (only internal display)
  - Duplicate (same desktop on both displays)
  - Extend (two different desktops)
  - Projector only (only TV)

- In Windows Vista, perform a right click on your desktop, go to **Personalize → Display Settings**, select the secondary display and deactivate **Extend the desktop onto this monitor**.
- In Windows XP, perform a right click on your desktop, go to **Properties → Settings**, select the secondary display and deactivate **Extend my Windows desktop onto this Monitor**.